# move pdf through clipboard

Tags: macos, mojave, copy-paste

```
$ cat scaswd.pdf| pbcopy
$ pbpaste > astasd.pdf
$ open astasd.pdf
```

astasd.pdf cannot be opened, but scaswd.pdf is a valid pdf file.

Is there a way I can stick a pdf onto my clipboard and paste it somewhere else?

---

I want to copy a file from my local computer to a remote one I can only access with ssh, without using intermediary file-hosting servers.

(I can't scp)

For text files copy and pasting between terminals works.

For binary files, like a pdf, I need another solution.

Comment: I think that mac doesnt support file copying this way. What are you trying to achieve? if you want to copy files in terminal there are easier ways.

Comment: @BenjaminScherer copy a file from my computer to a remote computer I can only access with ssh (I can't scp)

Comment: Do you have rsync?

Comment: @BenjaminScherer yes

Comment: rsync -avz localFolder/ root@192.168.0.101:/path/on/remote/

Comment: @BenjaminScherer won't work for the same reason scp doesn't work, the computer I need to copy to isn't accessible on the internet. I ssh to one computer, then I ssh to another one from that computer's local network. I guess I could do a 2-step rsync or scp

Comment: Id recommend you change your question with more details. From what you have said https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139417/how-to-scp-with-a-second-remote-host could help you.

Comment: `pbcopy < 1.pdf ; pbpaste > 2.pdf ; open 2.pdf` works fine for me in El Capitan.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page of pbcopy

> pbcopy  takes the standard input and places it in the specified
>   pasteboard. If no pasteboard is specified, the general pasteboard will
>   be used by
>          default.  T**he input is placed in the pasteboard as plain text data unless it begins with the Encapsulated PostScript (EPS)  file** 
>   **header  or  the**
>          *Rich Text Format (RTF) file header,* in which case it is placed in the pasteboard as one of those data types.

So from this it would seem that only documents with RTF format or EPS format can be copied and pasted from these commands.

Finder does support copy and pasting files however, so cmd c, and cmd v, will copy and paste files in finder.

Answer (score 2):

You can `cat` the pdf file and redirect the output to a file without using the clipboard.

```
cat scaswd.pdf > astasd.pdf; open astasd.pdf
```

Answer (score -1):

Partial or preliminary answer, needs work on the exact syntax, scripting experts, please help:

The *clipboard* can do a bit more than the `manpage` for `pbcopy` and `pbpaste` reveals. Obviously, most of us have copied and pasted something else then pure text. Pictures for example.

You might try something like this:

```
osascript -e 'set the clipboard to (read POSIX file ("/Users/YOU/test.pdf") as PDF file)'
```

The above is *not* the correct syntax near às PDF file` and will throw an error. But it works for JPEG files, PNGs etc.

Leaving out the latter part with the slightly incorrect input-syntax copies 'something' to the clipboard.
Checking the content with `osascript -e 'clipboard info' gives then not something like

> ```
> Unicode text, 92, string, 46, styled Clipboard text, 22, «class utf8», 46, «class ut16», 94
> ```

but

> ```
> astasd.pdf: PDF document, version 1.4
> ```

Only that this is then not copied out correctly.

`